# Do I have to manually merge a branch with master after pushing the branch to github?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-push

I am asking this question because I am slightly confused (only slightly).

As I am using `Pycharm` **(on a branch other than master)** it offers me the chance to commit and push changes of a branch to github.

**so I do just that.**

Now...

**After**, I run this:

```
current branch *test

1.git pull origin master
2.git checkout master
3.git merge test
```

on `1.` it tells me all is up to date. then going on to `3.` it also tells me all up to date with `master`.

Questions:

1. What happens when I commit-push a branch to github?
2. Do I have to run the code block above after I push that branch to master?

**EDIT**

1. I start of on the `master branch`
2. I run `git checkout test`.

a message appears.

```
switched to branch test. your branch is ahead of origin/test by 3 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

3. I run the command `git pull origin master`

**a message appears with many lines showing the branch being updated.**

4. I re-run the command `git pull origin master`

   a message appears from http://github.com/username/project

   - branch     master -> FETCH_HEAD
     Already up-to-date
5. I press the green button to commit changes and push. a pop-up appears `nothing to commit`
6. I run the command `git checkout master`

**your branch is already up to date with origin/master**

7. I run the command `git merge test`

   **ALL UP-TO-DATE !!!**

so why `git merge test`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you have to manually merge the branch . Because at the current state there are two branches in your repo. So if you want to merge the new branch to the master branch then

```
git checkout master
git merge <your-new-branch>
git push -u origin master
```

This should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

> on 1. it tells me all is up to date. then going on to 3. it also tells me all up to date with master.

```
$ git pull origin master
```

This commands does is equivalent to

```
$ git fetch origin master
$ git merge master
```

The first step downloads all the changes from the `master` branch in the `origin` remote (which is a nickname for your GitHub repo). The second command merges `master` (which now includes any changes from GitHub) into the current branch (`test`). Since you probably created the branch on `master` and have not made any other changes, you get the message that everything is up-to-date.

I am not sure why step 3 says everything is up-to-date with master. You probably did other commands which you have not posted here, either to commit the same changes directly to `master` or merge `test` previously.

> Questions:
>
> 1. What happens when i commit-push a branch to github?

When you push a branch to GitHub, then you create that branch in your GitHub repo along with the entire change history which it represents. Nothing changes with any other branches, including `master`.

> Do i have to run the code block above after i push that branch to master?

"push a branch to master" does not make any sense because `master` is also a branch. You can only push a branch to a **remote**. Or you can **merge** one branch into another branch.

To update your GitHub repo with your local changes, you have two choices:

1. Merge your branch to `master` manually and then push `master` to GitHub with

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   $ git merge test
   $ git push origin master
   ```

   Note that this only does steps 2 and 3 from your original commands. Your original Step 1 merges `master` into `test`. This is only necessary if `master` has changes and you want to check for merge conflicts and resolve them if they exist. Instead, you want to do the opposite: merge `test` into `master`. This is why I checkout `master` first then merge `test`.
2. Push the branch to GitHub and create a Pull Request in your GitHub repo. Then when you merge the PR, `master` on GitHub will be updated and you will need to pull the changes back to your local repo:

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   $ git pull origin master
   ```

p.s. You can do the equivalent of all of these commands inside PyCharm if you wish.

Comment: i just edited my post.  thank you for your reply. less confused but still confused.

Comment: @GeorgePamfilis I think you should reread the paragraph where I explain what `git pull origin master` does. In particular, it changes **the current branch** which is not necessarily `master`. I only use this command when someone else has made changes to master and I do `git checkout master` first so that I can update my own `master` with the other person's changes. Furthermore, rerunning the same command twice does not make any sense when the first attempt was successful. Even if the first attempt failed, you need to take the necessary actions to fix it before running the command again.

Comment: @GeorgePamfilis "so why `git merge test`?" I explain this in part 1 about updating your GitHub repo with your local changes. Hopefully my most recent edit is more clear than the original.